# Asp.Net MVC Razor View Editor Templates - passing variables between each iteration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

If I'm using an editor template for a repeating table row within a Razor view, is there anyway for my to pass a variable from one iteration of the editor template to the next?

For example - my model may have:

```
CarType
CarTypeDesc
CarModel
```

My view would have:

```
<table>
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CarList)
</table>
```

Ideally, I would like to have a heading of CarType and a list of CarModels under it, eg:

```
Type1 - this is the description of type 1
   CarModel1
   CarModel2
   CarModel3
Type1 - this is the description of type 2
   CarModel4
   CarModel5
Type3 - this is the description of type 3
   CarModel6
```

I can only get that view, if my template knows what the previous CarType was.

Thanks for any ideas,

Mark

Comment: You need to re-think your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend changing your view models to represent the concerns of the different views, so your Model would look like:

```
string CarType { get; set; }
string CarTypeDesc { get; set; }
IEnumerable<CarModel> CarModels { get; set; }
```

This then removes the need for your view models to be aware of the preceding one and more closely follows the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by creating custom templates for these properties:

```
<table>
   @for (int i = 0; i <= Model.Count; i++)
   {
       Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i].CarType, "CarTypeTemplate");
       Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i].CarModel, "CarModelTemplate");
   }
</table>
```

If you have particular data/class types for your `CarType` or `CarModel`, you can just create editor templates have the same name as these types, e.g. `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/CarType.cshtml`. Razor would use then these templates for rendering your properties. Then you could just keep your original `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CarList)` call. Inside these templates you could, for example, create `<tr>` elements with `padding-left: 20px;` for the `<td>` containing the `CarModel`.